# I can not get data from AJAX (jQuery Widget)

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax, jquery, ajaxaddtocart

**I need to get data from AJAX, but the Post is empty.**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Mymodule\Controller\Query;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context  $context,
        ResultFactory $resultJsonFactory

    ) {
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }



    public function execute()
    {
        var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        return $resultJson->setData(['success' => test]);
    }
}
```

In the code, Ajax enters, but Ajax does not send anything. **Help me please .**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui'
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.widget('namespace.module', {
        options: {
            triggerEvent: 'change',
            controller: 'http://developer.loc/namespace_module/query/custom'
        },

        _create: function() {
            console.log('3333');
            this._bind();
        },

        _bind: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.element.on(self.options.triggerEvent, function() {
                console.log('2222');
                self._ajaxSubmit();

            });

        },
        _ajaxSubmit: function() {
            console.log($('[data-role="cart-item-qty"]').val());
            console.log('1111');
            console.log(this.options.controller);
            $.ajax({
                url: this.options.controller,
                data: $('[data-role="cart-item-qty"]').val(),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(res) {
                    alert('ajax send');
                    console.log('ajax success');
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return $.namespace.module;
});
```

But if I write in the controller exit (); , then the trigger function success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ajax code by following

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.options.controller,
    data: 'qty='+$('[data-role="cart-item-qty"]').val(),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(res) {
        alert('ajax send');
        console.log('ajax success');
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```

Also change your controller execute method by

```
public function execute()
{
    var_dump($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    return $resultJson->setData(['success' => 'test']);
}
```